# Can a property in a class have a second name or an alias in .NET?

Tags: .net

Is there a way in .NET to have a class property have a second name or an alias. I want the alias to show in Visual Studio Intellisense? The reason is for me to know what property maps to what column in a database and if I put the column name somewhere with the corresponding property, I can easily know how the mappings work.

Comment: If you use the method that AdamRalph posted you'll obtain an Intellisense description under the property or function you are calling containing the text you entered in the <summary> tag, Even when you pass over the property or function with the mouse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put the column name in an XML comment on the property, e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Maps to column 'foo'
/// </summary>
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

The content of the XML comment will show in the intellisense tooltip for the Foo property.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is anyway to give it an alias, but you could easily create another property with a different name that just accesses the property you are trying to get to.

```
class MyClass
{
  private int myVal;

  public int MyProperty
  {
    get { return this.myVal; }
    set { this.myVal = value; }
  }

  public int MyDbProperty
  {
    get { return this.MyProperty; }
    set { this.MyProperty = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't help a developer understand which property maps to which column in the database via intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add another property assigning the one you want an "alias" for.

```
public String InnerProp { get; set; }
public String AliasProp
{
  get { return this.InnerProp; }
  set { this.InnerProp = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this at a metadata or even a language level.  However you can use simple properties that forward their requests to achieve the same result

```
public class Student {
  private  string _name;
  public string ColumnName { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
  public string Name { get { return ColumnName; } set { ColumnName = value; }}
}
```